# How to display a user's most recent activity?

Tags: trello, zapier, harvest

I have a teammate who wants to view exactly what I'm working on within our Trello boards at any given moment.

Has anyone figured out an elegant means of doing this using Trello features?

I also use Harvest, and was thinking that perhaps I could use Zapier to manipulate a card that would show either idle or working on X?

If you have an already completed solution you would like to share, please answer.

If you have suggestions, please put them in the question comments.

Does anyone know if Harvest has any webhooks?

My teammate wants to know *which* card I am currently working on *at that moment* - just to be clear.

Comment: Type your username in the search filed of Trello board, it will show you the cards you are/was working on.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh I see your point, however I am wondering if that list is ordered by the card I touched most recently?